# Couldn't build google mock

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I tried to build google mock on Windows 7 by using MinGW. But I couldn't.

I downloaded google test and google mock from the web site below by clicking 'Download Zip' button.
[https://github.com/google/googletest][1]

I unzipped the file and execute the command on the command line.

```
> g++ -c -Iinclude -I. src/gmock-all.cc
```

But the error occurred.

```
> include/gmock/internal/gmock-port.h:53:45: fatal error: gtest/internal/gtest-linked_ptr.h: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first build googletest, and then googlemock. It comes bundled
with googlemock in subdirectory named "gtest". This is what you need to do:

```
g++ -isystem <path_to_gtest>/include -I<path_to_gtest> \
  -isystem <path_to_gmock>/include -I<path_to_gmock> \
  -pthread -c <path_to_gtest>/src/gtest-all.cc
g++ -isystem <path_to_gtest>/include -I<path_to_gtest> \
  -isystem <path_to_gmock>/include -I<path_to_gmock> \
  -pthread -c <path_to_gmock>/src/gmock-all.cc
```

This will definately work on Linux, but I cant be 100% sure for MinGW on
Win7. If it does not help, I suggest using Visual Studio Community Edition.
You already have a VS solution setup in `<path_to_gmock>/msvc/2010`. It
is a solution for VS2010 but opening it with a newer version will prompt you
to upgrade the toolset. Simply accept and build the "gmock" project in that
solution.o_gmock>/src/gmock-all.cc